# R memory management: exponential increase in required memory for R's lm_robust function, vector allocation error

Tags: r, memory, regression, bigdata

I'm attempting to run a fixed-effects regression on a large dataset using the `estimatr` library's `lm_robust` function. My dataset has approximately 6 million rows across 8 variables, 7 of which are int/num types and one of is a char type.

My goal is to conduct a regression for a num variable based on 5 other num variables (columns), cluster with respect to my character variable, and run fixed-effects with respect to my character variable. When I do this, I get a large memory error on vector allocation:

```
> FER1 <- lm_robust(a ~ b + c + d + e + f, data = df, 
clusters = g, fixed_effects = ~g, se_type = "stata")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 739.7 Gb
```

By which, a - f are int/num types and g is the character type. There are around 20,000 unique values for the character type. I thought this was a bit strange, because the dataset as a whole used only about 2 Gb of memory, and 740 Gb seems far too large.

To debug this, I decided to partition the data and observe how the size of the vector required changes based on the number of obs (rows) in the dataset. First, I made a partition of the first 500k rows of the dataframe:

```
> df2 <- df[1:500000,]
> n_distinct(df2$g)
[1] 12188
> FER1 <- lm_robust(a ~ b + c + d + e + f, data = df2, 
clusters = g, fixed_effects = ~g, se_type = "stata")
> object_size(FER1)
45.01 MB
```

I use the `object_size` function from the `pryr` library to determine the size of the object created. I then created another partition, for the first 750k rows of the dataframe:

```
> df2 <- df[1:750000,]
> n_distinct(df2$g)
[1] 12919
> FER1 <- lm_robust(a ~ b + c + d + e + f, data = df2, 
clusters = g, fixed_effects = ~g, se_type = "stata")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 62.6 Gb
```

I though this was very strange, because it appeared that only 250k more obs resulted in around a 62 Gb increase in vector size. This is not proportionate to what one would expect, given that the first 500k rows only needed 40 Mb. Thus, I created a third partition to run, for the 250k obs between row 500,000 and row 750,000:

```
> df2 <- df[500000:750000,]
> FER1 <- lm_robust(a ~ b + c + d + e + f, data = df2, 
clusters = g, fixed_effects = ~g, se_type = "stata")
> object_size(FER1)
23.27 MB
```

I'm confused now because I thought the memory required for a regression on df[1:750000] should be equal to the memory required for df[1:500000] + df[500000:750000], but evidently it is not so. How/why is this the case? I assume it has something to do with the way R, or more specifically `lm_robust` allocates computer memory for vectors, but couldn't find anything in the function documentation discussing this. I'm loosely familiar with the concept of memory fragmentation, but not sure that it applies in this case due to the vector allocation size errors.

More broadly, any suggestions as to implementing a fixed-effects regression on a dataset of this size?

Comment: Can you outline the range of values for each column so a sample dataset can be created? e.g. number of unique strings in df$g, and the range and type of values for each of the a-f columns? With that info, I'll see if I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @LeroyTyrone Sure. df$g has 19.6k unique character values, and I pulled the following information on the range of the values from the summary function: 
df$a: ranges from -1 to 1 with majority of values being 0.00 (1st/3rd quartiles are 0.00)
df$b: ranges from 0 to 1 with majority of values being 1 (1st/3rd quartiles are 1) 
df$c: ranges from 0 to 1 with majority of values being 0 (1st/3rd quartiles are 0)
df$d: ranges from 0 to 200k (1st/3rd quartiles are 15 and 400)
df$e: num values from 1 to 10: median/mean around 7
df$f: ranges from 0 to 2mil (1st/3rd quartiles are 100 and 2500)